# Image and text on the same line React Native

Tags: react-native

I read about making the image inline with the text and since there is no inline-block property i found that this is the code that make it happen but i have no luck with this:

```
topContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        flexWrap: "nowrap"
    }
```

This is my all code maybe i have not notice something related to the code above that it does not make it work:

```
export default class PostItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View styles={styles.container}>
                <View styles={styles.topContainer}>
                    <Image style={styles.userImg} source={{ uri: this.props.item.user.picture }} />
                    <Text style={styles.name}>{this.props.item.user.name}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.date}>{this.props.item.created}</Text>
                </View>

                <Text style={styles.body}>{this.props.item.body}</Text>

                <Image style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: 400 }} source={{ uri: this.props.item.image }} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        marginBottom: 20
    },
    topContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        flexWrap: "nowrap",
        justifyContent: "flex-end"
    },
    userImg: {
        borderRadius: 50,
        width: 55,
        height: 55,
        marginLeft: 10
    },
    name: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        fontWeight: "600",
        color: "black"
    },
    date: {
        color: "#999",
        marginLeft: 10
    },
    body: {
        paddingVertical: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 20
    }
})
```

It look like this [image]

Comment: Can you try changing `topContainer`s `flexDirection` to `column` please.

Comment: @bennygenel Its fixed now. I was using styles instead of style